# biblatex package error: outdated xstrings package

Tags: biblatex, packages, xstring

I am having a hard time to get my latex running again, I am about to write a PhD thesis. When i compiled my current files, some packages were missing, but the on the fly installation took care of that until i got the error

```
! Package biblatex Error: Outdated 'xstring' package.
```

This persisted all my efforts so far that I will describe in the following:

1. un-reinstalling xstring package; manually remove and download, checked package manager for the date: packaged 2013-10-23, seems the latest.
2. outcommented the `\includepackage[...]{biblatex}` but the error persisted
3. condensed the file to

   ```
   \documentclass[12pt]{article}
   \begin{document}  
   lorem ipsum
   \end{document}
   ```

   but the error still persisted
4. closed the project, opened a new file and compiled the above minimal code - no problem
5. no clue anymore how to handle it, ask stackexchange for help
6. [edit] as writing the post, i realize the few lines above the error message:

   ```
   Writing index file Dissertation.idx
   (C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\biblatex\biblatex.sty
   (C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\logreq\logreq.sty
   (C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\logreq\logreq.def))
   (C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\url\url.sty)
   (C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\xstring\xstring.sty
   (xstring.tex))

   ! Package biblatex Error: Outdated 'xstring' package.
   ```

   and replace the above xstring.sty with the newly downloaded one from

   ```
   C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\xstring
   ```

   but the error persists

potentially interesting info:

- Win7
- Miktex 2.9
- WinEdt 9
- it *did* compile a few weeks ago when i worked on it last time
- original preamble:

  ```
      %Typische Dissvorlage im Tex-Style
  % Einstellungen für das IACETH der ETH Zürich
  % von Marc Wüest (2001)
  % Modifikationen Jörg Mäder (2003)

  % Mehr wichtige Infos unter
  % http://iacweb.ethz.ch/en/various/Mittelbau/disslatex.html

  % Erstellen in UNIX (evt in einem Skript ablegen: diss_script)
  %  latex diss_main.tex
  %  makeindex diss_main
  %  bibtex diss_main
  %  latex diss_main.tex
  %  latex diss_main.tex
  %  dvips -o diss_main.ps diss_main.dvi
  %  gv diss_main.ps


  \documentclass[12pt]{ETHthesis}

  %%Language
  \usepackage{E}
  %%ETH-Layout
  \usepackage{ETHthesis}
  %%

  % vereinfachtes Eingeben von Leerschlägen hinter Shortcut-Commands
  % Beispiel: \newcommand{\DNA}{deoxyribose nucleid acid\xspace}
  %\usepackage{xspace}

  %????
  %\usepackage{foot}

  %Verbessertes Float-Handling mit Schalter H (gleiche Position wie im Skript)
  \usepackage{float}
  %%Force to place figures only after they have been referenced for the first time
  \usepackage{flafter}
  %%Enables \FloatBarrier command
  \usepackage{placeins}
  %%
  %%for landscape pages
  \usepackage{pdflscape}
  %%

  %%Subfigure package
  \usepackage{subfigure}
  %
  \renewcommand{\thesubfigure}{[\alph{subfigure}]}
  \renewcommand{\thesubtable}{[\alph{subtable}]}

  %%Some different symbol packages
  \usepackage{amssymb}
  %\usepackage{amstext}
  %\usepackage{amsfonts}
  %\usepackage{amsbsy}
  %\usepackage{amscd}
  %\usepackage{latexsym}
  \usepackage{amsmath}
  %%
  \usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}

  %% package for rotating figures
  \usepackage{rotating}

  %including graphics files, rotating parts of a page, and scaling parts of a page
  \usepackage{graphicx}
  \usepackage{epstopdf}
  %%Package for table formatting
  %\usepackage{tabularx}
  %%

  %%

  %%Definitions for CV
  \newcommand{\entrylabel}[1]{\mbox{#1}\hfil}
  \newenvironment{CV}
    {\begin{list}{}
      {\renewcommand{\makelabel}{\entrylabel}
      \setlength{\labelwidth}{84pt}
      \setlength{\leftmargin}{84pt}
    }}
    {\end{list}
  }
  %%

  %besserer eps import: \eps import ERSETZEN durch \epsfig
  %\usepackage{epsf}

  %%Setting language
  \usepackage[english,german]{babel}

  \usepackage{csquotes}% Recommended by some webpage
  %%

  %%Setting page
  \usepackage{a4}
  %%

  %%Package to enable line spacing set-up
  \usepackage{setspace}
  %%

  %% package for displaying rotated pages
  \usepackage{pdflscape}

  %% package for frames around figures
  %%\usepackage{mdframed}

  %%Definition of input encoding to allow öä etc.
  %\usepackage[ansinew]{inputenc}    % utf8 support       %!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
  %\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}       % code for pdf file  %!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
  \usepackage{ae}

  %%Setting the fontfamily
  \renewcommand{\familydefault}{\rmdefault}
  %\renewcommand{\familydefault}{phv}
  %%

  %entsprechend Eintragen und Auskommetierung aufheben
  %\graphicspath{{}{/home/DEINNAME/DAS/VERZEICHNIS}{/WO/AUCH/IMMER}}

  %%PAGE LAYOUT
  \setlength{\topmargin}{-10mm}
  \setlength{\headheight}{5.mm}
  \setlength{\headsep}{+15.mm}
  \setlength{\textheight}{220mm}
  \setlength{\footskip}{+20.mm}
  \setlength{\textwidth}{161mm}
  \setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0mm}
  \setlength{\evensidemargin}{0mm}
  \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

  %%Skip between the paragraphs
  \setlength{\parskip}{1ex plus 0.0ex minus 0.0ex}
  %%

  %%New values
  \setcounter{topnumber}{2}
  \setcounter{bottomnumber}{2}
  \setcounter{totalnumber}{4}
  \renewcommand{\topfraction}{0.85}
  \renewcommand{\bottomfraction}{0.85}
  \renewcommand{\textfraction}{0.15}
  \renewcommand{\floatpagefraction}{0.7}
  %%

  %%Original values
  %\renewcommand{\floatpagefraction}{0.9}
  %\renewcommand{\topfraction}{0.9}
  %\renewcommand{\bottomfraction}{0.9}
  %\renewcommand{\textfraction}{0.1}
  %\renewcommand{\textfloatsep}{5mm}
  \renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.15}
  %%

  \initETHthesis
  \makeindex %Needed line

  %%New command for degree sign
  \newcommand{\grad}{\ensuremath{^\circ}}
  %%

  \providecommand{\e}[1]{\ensuremath{\times 10^{#1}}}

  %%The natbib package is a reimplementation of the LATEX \cite command AND INCOMPATIBLE WITH BIBLATEX!!
  %\usepackage[numbers,compress]{natbib}

  % Start of 'ignore natbib' hack
  %\let\bibhang\relax
  %\let\citename\relax
  %\let\bibfont\relax
  %\let\Citeauthor\relax
  %\expandafter\let\csname ver@natbib.sty\endcsname\relax
  % End of 'ignore natbib' hack

    \usepackage[
    backend=biber,
    style=alphabetic,
    natbib=true,
    ]{biblatex}
  \emergencystretch=1em % removes overful box warning in the bibliography

  %das File mit den Referenzen drin,
  %\bibliography{mendeley/library}
  \addbibresource{mendeley/library.bib}

  %%Package used for the acronym list
  \usepackage[printonlyused,withpage]{acronym}
  %\usepackage[printonlyused,nohyperlinks]{acronym}
  %%

  %%Package used for the nomenclature
  \usepackage{nomencl}
  \setlength{\nomitemsep}{-\parsep} %Linespacing
  \makenomenclature %Needed line
  %%

  %\usepackage{bookmark}

  %%Package used for the tables
  \usepackage{booktabs}
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}%Linespacing
  %%

  %% package for using chemical formulae
  \usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}

  %package for SI units
  \usepackage[per-mode=fraction]{siunitx}
  \DeclareSIUnit\year{a}

  %% package for using colors
  \usepackage{xcolor}

  %% use document intern hyperlinks, needs xcolor
  %\usepackage{hyperref}
  \usepackage[bookmarks,raiselinks,pageanchor,
                          hyperindex,colorlinks,
                          citecolor=blue!80!black,
                          linkcolor=blue!80!black,
                          urlcolor=blue!80!black,
                          filecolor=blue!80!black,
                          menucolor=orange,
                          %pagebackref,
                          pdfauthor={Christian Bolesch},
                          pdftitle={Heated Neutron Tomography}
                          ]{hyperref}

  %%Formatting of the font used in Acronyms
  %\renewcommand{\bflabel}[1]{{\textbf{#1}\hfill}}
  %%
  %\usepackage[titletoc]{appendix}

  %ALLOWS WHITEPAGE IN THE BOTTOM OF THE PAGE
  \raggedbottom
  %PENALTIES FOR LEAVING LAST LINE OF PARAGRAPH ON THE NEXT PAGE
  \widowpenalty=10000 %more than one line (beginning)
  \clubpenalty=10000 %more than one line (end)

  %%DISABLE HYPHENATION
  %\tolerance=1
  % \emergencystretch=\maxdimen
  % \hyphenpenalty=10000
  % \hbadness=10000
  %%%

  %\includeonly{design}

  %% Chris specific stuff
  \newcommand{\kgpmmm}{\si[per-mode=fraction]{\kilogram\per\cubic\meter}}
  \newcommand{\kjpkg}{\si[per-mode=fraction]{\kilo\joule\per\kilogram}}
  \usepackage{footnote}
  \usepackage{threeparttable}
  \makesavenoteenv{tabular}
  \makesavenoteenv{table}
  \usepackage{afterpage} %intended to fix the half empty pages before landscape pages

  %\raggedbottom % supposedly to force footnotes on the bottom of the page where tey apear

  \usepackage{dcolumn}
  \newcolumntype{d}[1]{D{.}{.}{#1}}
  ```

thanks for any help!

Comment: (1) Welcome, (2) did you update your miktex, both as user and admin?

Comment: Given that with the document in 3 you still got an error about biblatex, I guess you could try deleting auxiliary files in your folder and rebuild. But I suppose that won't send away the original message on the full document.

Comment: You have an (xstring.tex) in your document folder. Remove or rename this. And don't exchange files manually, this only lead into chaos and makes it rather difficult to help you.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer 
>>You have an (xstring.tex) in your document folder. Remove or rename this.
you nailed it. thanks! => I'd mark it as solution if i found the button

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an `xstring.tex` in your document folder. Remove or rename this file.